# OrCAD - diode characteristic with different temperatures

Tags: orcad

I have a basic circuit with diode, resistor, and a voltage source.
I am getting the following error when trying to change the X Axis variable to **Vd** (diode voltage):

**ERROR(ORPROBE-3217): Only 1 expression allowed for the X variable**.

I have set three different temperatures in **Temperature (Sweep)**.
Default variable for X Axis is the voltage source, and when trying to change it to **V(D1)** which is a diode voltage, it gives the above error.

My question is how to get diode characteristic (or any other characteristic) **Id=f(Vd)** when multiple temperatures are used in the same simulation?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your **Primary Sweep** will be the diode characteristic where you vary Id and plot Vd (use a **current source** to make Id). The **Secondary Sweep** will be a couple of temperature points.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, Is voltage source V1 still in sweep variable? If not, what should be in sweep variable?

Comment: @FakeMoustache, Does it have to be a global parameter?

Comment: Instead of asking, just **try it** and see what happens. Fortunately circuit simulators don't blow up when you do the wrong thing so you can just experiment. I could "hold your hand" and point to where you have to click the mouse for every step. But if you really need to learn this then you will need to do this yourself.